# XSL with X12 850 document intellisense issues

Tags: xslt, biztalk, x12

I've been mapping various documents in XSL using visual studio with great success. The intellisense is particularly fantastic. When I am going from document X such as an SAP IDoc to an X12 855 or 850 the intellisense works beautifully. That is to say when the target doc is X12 it works. I am now in the position where I have to map from an X12 850 to an SAP IDoc and the intellisense is totally broken. I've narrowed it down to this namespace declaration. As soon as I add  xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006" the intellisense no longer shows me the available tags.

Without that declaration I get the intellisense for all the xsl:for-each, xsl-if, etc... when I add the declaration all I get is !--, ![CDATA[, and ?

**Has anyone run into this problem?**

Here's the XSL I use to reproduce the issue (In Visual Studio 2013)

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0" version="1.0" 
xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Edi/PropertySchema" 
xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:X12_00401_850" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/s0:X12_00401_850">
<ns0:ISA06>
<xsl:value-of select="ST/ST01/text()" />
</ns0:ISA06>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is this a BizTalk app?  If so, why aren't  you using the Mapper?

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the name spaces in the declaration?

Comment: Johns, Mapping to an IDOC format using the mapper is a huge pain. Because the SAP IDocs have tons of repeating segments that make it nearly impossible to map using the functoids. When you have to turn repeating segments into other repeating segments it's extremely difficult or next to impossible. In my last project, which was exclusively using IDocs, I found it immensely easy to just code the xsl directly.  Plus you get to use the full power of the language such as searching, if statements, case statements (choose), etc..

Comment: Pieter, I just tried it and it didn't work. Tried different orders but seems like the same issue.